# Level object collision

Tags: c++, collision, sdl-2

I'm using SDL2 for my game.

I have an std::vector of SDL_Rects (that is, rectangle objects) that holds the solid platforms (i.e. platforms that the player can't go through) of a level in my game.

When checking for collision, my current code does the following:

```
for (SDL_Rect rect : rects) {
    if (player.collides(rect)) {
        // handle collision
    }
}
```

Consider I have a level with numerous (e.g. 500) solid platform rectangles, is it inefficient to go through all of them and check for collision? Is there a better way to do this?

The collides() function only checks for AABB collision (4 simple conditions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is reasonable. You have simple shapes and are doing simple collision checking. Imagine a more graphically intense game. Even then, they may have a complex skeletal mesh for the character, but just do the collision checking against an easy-to-calculate bounding shape, and they probably have a lot more than 500 things going on at once.

In a more complex game engine, different types may be blocking against some types and non-blocking against others, so not only will it be checking for simple overlap events, it has to know if the overlapping objects should interact or not. Or there might be different interactions for different objects.

With games, by and large your bottleneck is rendering and the associated calculations, so unless you know you're in danger of doing something incredibly slowly with the game logic (complex path finding or AI or something like that), I would concentrate my optimizing efforts on the rendering.